# Finding the coordinates of point D using vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am really struggling with this question:

[image]
Transcribing:

Points $A$, $B$, and $C$ have coordinates $A(1,3)$, $B(5,-1)$, and $C(2,-8)$.
Point $D$ is such that $\vec{AD}=\vec{BC}+2x\vec{AB}+3y\vec{AC}\ =\vec{AB}+2x\vec{AC}+3y\vec{BC}$.
Find the coordinates of $D$.

---

Here is my attempt, but I have gotten in a muddle, could someone explain how they would tackle this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake comes from representing point $D$ using variables that already exist in the given equations.  Hopefully my solution below is sufficiently clear for you to follow.

Let $D$ be located at $(m,n)$.  In the equation that you have, we want to calculate $\vec{AD}$, $\vec{AB}$, $\vec{AC}$, and $\vec{BC}$.

\begin{align}
\vec{AD}&=(m,n)-(1,3)=(m-1,n-3)\\
\vec{AB}&=(5,-1)-(1,3)=(4,-4)\\
\vec{AC}&=(2,-8)-(1,3)=(1,-11)\\
\vec{BC}&=(2,-8)-(5,-1)=(-3,-7)\\
\end{align}

We then have
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\vec{AD}&=\vec{BC}+2x\vec{AB}+3y\vec{AC}\ &=\vec{AB}+2x\vec{AC}+3y\vec{BC}\\
(m-1,n-3)&=(-3,-7)+2x(4,-4)+3y(1,-11)\ &=(4,-4)+2x(1-11)+3y(-3,-7)\\
(m-1,n-3)&=(8x+3y-3,-8x-33y-7)\ &=(2x-9y+4,-22x-21y-4)
\end{alignat*}

Using the second and third columns, we have the system of equations

$$\left\{\begin{align}
2x-9y+4&=8x+3y-3\\
-22x-21y-4&=-8x-33y-7
\end{align}\right.$$
Simplifying, this gives us
$$\left\{\begin{align}
0&=6x+12y-7&\qquad (1)\\
0&=14x-12y-3&\qquad (2)
\end{align}\right.$$

Then,
\begin{align}
(1)+(2):\quad 0&=20x-10\\
x&=\frac12
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
(1):\quad 0&=6(\frac12)+12y-7\\
0&=12y-4\\
y&=\frac13\end{align}

Finally, using the first and second columns in the three-column set of equations above, we have
\begin{align}
(m-1,n-3)&=(8(\frac12)+3(\frac13)-4,-8(\frac12)-33(\frac13)-7)\\
(m-1,n-3)&=(4+1-3,-4-11-7)\\
(m-1,n-3)&=(2,-22)\end{align}

Simultaneously solve
\begin{align}
m-1&=2\\
m&=3\\
n-3&=-22\\
n&=-19\end{align}
Therefore, point $D$ is located at $(3,-19)$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Your method is correct, but there are a couple of small errors towards the end. For example, we should have $m-1=4+1-3=2$ hence $m=3$, and $n-3=-22$ shows that $n=-19$. So point D is actually (3, -19), but I still understood your method, thanks.

Comment: Yikes, terrible simple arithmetic mistake on my end.